# "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Skip'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selectlist

I’m trying to create a team of players, there are 4 players per team so I have 4 select lists that contain and populate the players in the league. When I go to save the team the error:

> "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Skip'`

The CreateTeam controller:

```
public ActionResult CreateLeagueTeam(int? id)
{
    int leagueId = id.Value;
    League league = db.Leagues.Include(x=>x.Members).First(l=> l.Id == leagueId);
    var leagueMemberList = league.Members.ToList();
    var leagueMemberSelectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach(Member m in leagueMemberList)
    {
        leagueMemberSelectListItems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = m.FirstName + " " + m.LastName, Value = m.Id.ToString() });
    }
    ViewData["leagueMemberList"] = leagueMemberSelectListItems;
    return View();  
}
```

the HTTP POST ActionResult:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreateLeagueTeam([Bind(Include = "skip")] Team team)
{           
    team.IsBonspiel = false;
    team.IsLeague = true;
    // team.Name = team.Skip.LastName;
    team.YearActive = games.getSeasonYear();
    //finds and sets the league ID for the team
    int leagueId = (int)Session["leagueId"];
    League league = db.Leagues.Find(leagueId);
    team.League = league;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Teams.Add(team);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(team);
}
```

Finally the view where the Error is getting thrown:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Skip", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Skip, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.leagueMemberList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Also the Team Model:

```
public class Team: Entity
{
    [Required]
    public bool IsBonspiel { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool IsLeague { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int YearActive { get; set; }
    public int? SkipId { get; set; }
    public Member Skip { get; set; }
    public string BonspielSkip { get; set; }
    public List<BonspielTeamMember> BonspielMembers { get; set; }
    public List<Member> Members { get; set; }
    public List<Game> Games { get; set; }
    public Bonspiel Bonspiel { get; set; }
    public League League { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are multiple errors with your code.

1. `Skip` is a complex object and you cannot bind a `<select>` to a
   complex object. Based on your view, it should be
   `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SkipId, ...)`
2. You do not have a `ViewBag` property named `leagueMemberList`
   (change the controller code to `ViewBag.leagueMemberList =
   leagueMemberSelectListItems;` or the view code to
   `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SkipId,
   (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["leagueMemberList"], ...)`
3. You do not reassign the value of `ViewData["leagueMemberList"]` (or
   `ViewBag.leagueMemberList`) in the POST method if `ModelState` is
   invalid and you return the view, which will result in a different
   exception because it will be `null` (Refer [this
   question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o)
4. Your `[Bind(Include = "skip")]` code in the POST method means that
   `ModelState` will always be invalid because you exclude every
   property of the model from binding (except `Skip` and you dont post
   any values for `Skip`)

Answer (score 0):

You added data to "ViewData" but you try to access from ViewBag.
You should know ViewData is different with ViewBag.
Therefore you try to change this line:

```
 ViewData["leagueMemberList"] = leagueMemberSelectListItems;
```

to => ViewBag.leagueMemberList = leagueMemberSelectListItems;

Comment: ah i didnt realise I switched it but Now I am getting thrown
this error:
The ViewData item that has the key 'Members' is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[EloraCurling.Models.Member, EloraCurling, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.

Comment: maybe after post action the ViewBag.leagueMemberList is null.
you need to reassign values to viewbag again.

Comment: but shouldnt when I hit submit it pass the values that are selected to the HttpPost action?

Comment: yes, it can but  having many errors in your code,the post action only send your selected value (Member.ID) to server but you want to bind it into Model.Skip so it can not be mapped.